# Tkinter label text position

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Simple question I thought I knew the answer to.  How do you make it so the text lines up on the left hand side of a label?  I have two labels on my window that I'm updating the text in the labels whenever I move the mouse, it's showing the x-y coordinates of the mouse(x position = ****** and y position = ******).  The problem is the text is bouncing on me which indicates it isn't lined up on the left hand side of the label.  I've tried anchor = 'w' but that isn't working.  The text(x position = ), x position = still bounces as I move the mouse around the screen.

edit:

This is used to create the window

```
s = Frame(self, width=150, height=20)
s.pack_propagate(0)
s.place(x=0,y=680)
v = Label(s, fg='black',anchor='w')
```

This is used to update the window

```
v.config(text = "x-position: " + str(px),anchor='w')
```

s and v are set global

That code doesn't anchor the text on the left of the window.  'x-position:' moves left and right around the window depending on how many numbers follow the ': '.

Comment: `anchor-'w'` is how you get text to be left-aligned in the label. Please show us some code. Read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How do you layout the label? Using `grid()` or `pack()` or `place()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `justify='left'` parameter to the label:

```
s = Frame(self, width=150, height=20)
s.pack_propagate(0)
s.place(x=0,y=680)
v = Label(s, fg='black',anchor='w', justify='left')
```